# Unable to click on a button inside an iframe

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:
Launch http://www.indiabookstore.net/.
Click on **FB like button** which is inside an iframe. (scroll down to see it)

Issue:
I'm able to switch to the iframe, but couldn't click on the button, as there is a **NoSuchElementException**

I tried giving relative as well as absolute xpaths, didn't work.

Comment: Try by putting some wait like wait for element to be displayed.

Comment: When i clicked on FB Like button, it shows me in a separate window. If it is a separate window, you need to use driver.switchTo().Window(). For detailed explanation about switching windows, watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugAPaofq1nQ    If it displays in a separate frame then use driver.switchTo.Frame(). For detailed explanation watch below video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYv_7-zYz4k

Comment: @Uday The question is regrading clicking on facebook like button. The reason OP might not be able to click on the button might be driver is not able to switch to the iframe that OP provided.

Comment: @VivekSingh Thank u for the reply. I am certain that I am able to switch to the frame(able to fetch the text '43K' which is in the next td under the same iframe), but I'm unable to click on the button even after using WebDriverWait.

Comment: @Uday, thanks for ur help too ..I agree with ur logic for clicking on twitter button,ideally should be the same for my scenario too,but it simply won't work..I'm looking for a solution to click on the FB like button bro..

Comment: I too tried couple of attempts to load FB there, but with Firefox WebDriver instance it not loading FB, did you noticed that? Because it is not available, it will throw error. I tried refresh the page, but still FB frame is not loaded. But, manually it loading FB.

Comment: Where is your sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Try out this way...

```
driver.switchTo().frame(
        driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(2));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
        .xpath("(//span[.='Like'])[1]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried couple of times executing through WebDriver, but facebook like button is not coming up. So i tried for Twitter with below code, which worked for me.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.indiabookstore.net/");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='home-twitter']")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='label']")).click();
```

Watch the above said video else watch this video to know more about switch between frames: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYv_7-zYz4k

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for fb Like button:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.indiabookstore.net/");

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[11]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/iframe")));
WebElement fb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/form/div/div[1]"));//fb Like button

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(fb).click().build().perform();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```